# How to get private endpoint aware connection string from MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, networking, mongodb-atlas

According to these docs, once the private endpoint is set up I should be able to go to the DB instance, select `Connect`, then select `Private Endpoint`, and then I should be able to get a private endpoint aware connection string that will resolve to that private endpoint.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-private-endpoint/#std-label-connect-private-endpoint

But I have set up the endpoint and it is live and yet when I go to `Connect`, no option for `Private Endpoint` is available.

Here is what I see:
[image]

Here is what I should see:
[image]

The cluster instance is M50 type, which should have this feature. Does anyone have pointers?

Comment: The first line says what to do: "You need to secure your MongoDB Atlas cluster before you can use it."  If no IP addresses can connect, and there are no users that can log in, there is no point in having a connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this might be possibly be related to : https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/private-endpoint-connect-option-is-not-available/219655